# How to implement firebase auth for all pages?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Authentication for my website. When a user wants to create a new account, log in or log out, he can do it on the login page. But when I call the function to get the current user on another page (index), it's null -> which means he's not logged in. When I then go back to the login page, the user is logged in as normal. How can I make sure that the user is logged in on all the pages in the website? Thanks!

```
firebase.auth().onAuthChanged(function(user) {
    if(user) {
        console.log("logged in");
    } else {
        console.log("logged out");
    }
})
```

both files are linked to this javascript.

Comment: Can provide some code? How are you retrieving the user exactly?

Comment: Seems like you would want to use the same code on every page then?

Comment: yes, I think this is the most important part of the code

Comment: hmm yes, but how could I do it differently?

Comment: *I call the function to get the current user on another page* What function are you calling? Once a user is authenticated, they stay authenticated unless something changes that. How do you know they are authenticated in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

you have to add a guard file with the function `CanActivate`

**guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';  
    import {  CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router } from '@angular/router';  
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';  
    import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';

    @Injectable({   providedIn: 'root' }) export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {   constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

      canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean | UrlTree {
          const currentUser = this.authService.isAuthenticated();
          if (currentUser) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return this.router.parseUrl('/sign-in');
        }

      } }
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
  getCurrentUserToken() {
      firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()/*.getToken()*/
      .then(
        (token: string) => {
          localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', JSON.stringify(token));
        }
      );
      localStorage.getItem('UserisLoggedNotIn');
    }

    isAuthenticated(): boolean {
       return (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn')) ? true : false;
       // return (this.userId) ? true : false;
    }

isAuthenticated(): boolean {
       return (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn')) ? true : false;
       // return (this.userId) ? true : false;
    }
```